How to pass shell command from helm values.yaml file to deployment.yaml
I got Dockerfile to build image for python application.
I got entrypoint.sh script that run uwsgi server.
Then there is a deployment yaml to run this image.
I created helm chart for that so in deployment.yaml I got
spec: containers: command: {{ .Values.api.command_to_run }}

In values.yaml I got: command_to_run: "[/bin/sh -c /app/entrypoint-prod.sh]"
How to pass such from values.yaml file

When would you need this to be changed at deploy time?  How would an administrator know what commands make sense?  Should this be a fixed value in your deployment spec, or in your image?

I want to modify/change at deploy time. So in values file during deploy I want to chcange script name - enteypoint.sh

In a PodSpec, the command: and args: (overriding Dockerfile ENTRYPOINT and CMD, respectively) are both lists of strings.  You need to make sure the output of your template is a list as well.  The Go text/template language isn't aware of YAML syntax at all; an expression like {{ .Values.api.command_to_run }} will be serialized in a Go-native format that isn't necessarily valid here.
If the command is a single word, this is probably the easiest case.  You don't need to wrap most commands in sh -c unless you're specifically using shell features (variable expansions, multiple commands in one string), and you shouldn't need to explicitly name a program's interpreter either.
# values.yaml
api:
  command_to_run: /app/entrypoint-prod.sh

# templates/deployment.yaml
command:
  - {{ .Values.api.command_to_run }}

If the format in the values file is a list of shell words, the easiest approach in Helm is to serialize it with toYaml.  Note that this will split out the list items one to a line, so it needs to be on its own line, and properly indented.
# values.yaml
api:
  command_to_run:
    - /bin/sh
    - '-c'
    - |
        if [ -z "$ENV" ]; then
          echo "ENV must be set" >&2
          exit 1
        fi
        exec "/app/entrypoint-$ENV.sh"

# templates/deployment.yaml
command:
{{ .Values.api.command_to_run | toYaml | indent 2 }}


spec:
containers:
- name: apideployment
image: backendimageuser999prod1
command:
{{ .Values.api.command_to_run | indent 2 }}
and there is a error during helm installation:
$ helm install deployment-test desg-chart --values desg-chart/values-dev.yaml
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: template: desg-chart/templates/api.yaml:31:47: executing "desg-chart/templates/api.yaml" at <2>: wrong type for value; expected string; got []interface {}
Line 31 is line : {{ .Values.api.command_to_run | indent 2 }}

Whoops, in the text I mentioned toYaml but I failed to include it in the example.  I've edited that in.

still error:
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: YAML parse error on deployment.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 25: did not find expected key.
Line 25 is {{ .Values.api.command_to_run | toYaml | indent 2 }}
I changed the code in values to debug:     - /bin/sh
- '-c'
- "sleep 100"
but still the same error.

If you have something like this in a Helm template:
...
spec:
  containers:
  - name: ...
    image: ...
    command: 
      - {{ .Values.api.command_to_run }}

Then your .Values file should contain values like:
api:
  command_to_run: "[/bin/sh -c /app/entrypoint-prod.sh]"


Ok thanks but still errors:
* Deployment in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Deployment: json: cannot unmarshal array into Go struct field Container.spec.template.spec.containers.command of type string

@user1666649 mine is the answer to the question: How to pass such from values.yaml file?. Regarding the other errors, please edit your question and add more details such as the complete deployment template and corresponding values.

I changed in values.yaml file:
command_to_run: ["/bin/sh", "entrypoint-prod.sh"]

and in deployemt.yaml:
command: {{ .Values.api.command_to_run }} 

Container lauches but with errors:
Error: failed to start container "api": Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/bin/sh entrypoint-prod.sh": stat /bin/sh entrypoint-prod.sh: no such file or directory: unknown
Back-off restarting failed container api in pod api-deployment-7c9f6876db-ctszb_esg(edeff61c-6a14-4b7b-81dd-bae0c243e89f)

Thats means there is no entrypoint-prod.sh file.
If I run pwd or ls command:
command: ["/bin/sh"]
args: ["-c", "pwd"]

the path is ok and inside of it there is entrypoint-prod.sh file.
